# Android Google Maps API V2 - Animation after Map start

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, android-maps-v2

I would like to add an animation after the map is loaded. 
My Problem is, i dont know when the map is ready. 
If i start the animation after my "setUpMapIfNeeded"-function , 
i see the animation, but whitout map content.

Is there any function which tells me when the map content is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and ended with subclassing MapFragment and calling a Callback interface at `onViewCreated`:

```
public class TLMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

private TLMapCallBack callback;

public interface TLMapCallBack{
    public void onMapCreated();
}

public static TLMapFragment newInstance(TLMapCallBack callback){
    TLMapFragment fragment = new TLMapFragment();
    fragment.callback = callback;
    return fragment;
}

public TLMapFragment(){
    callback = null;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(TAG, "onViewCreated");
    initMap();
    if(callback != null)
        callback.onMapCreated();
}

private void initMap(){
       //init map here
}
}
```

Comment: i dont quiet understand your code. I'm using a FragmentActivity, is it still possible to implement your solution? are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a sample onCreateview for a Map Fragment

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater arg0, ViewGroup arg1, Bundle arg2) {

        View v = super.onCreateView(arg0, arg1, arg2);    

        // init map
        mGoogleMap = getMap();

        // map loaded
        mGoogleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                Log.d(LOG_CATEGORY, "map loaded");
                // do other stuff

            }
        });


        return v;
    }
```